# Getting the error - name 'model' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to python, and I was trying to run this code on loading the model for building extraction. But it throws the error that the name 'model' is not found. I am unable to resolve it. Can anyone please help.

[image]

This is the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from loss import bce_dice_loss, dice_coef


model = load_model('D:\RESEARCH\IITR\BUILDING_EXTRACTION_PhD_Final_WORK\DATASET\ISPRS_DATASET\Toronto\Toronto\ImagesDolon\output\weights\my_model.h5',custom_objects={ 'bce_dice_loss': bce_dice_loss}) # Load BCE Dice Loss from loss.py into model
```

The error:

```
`ValueError`                                `Traceback (most recent call last)`
`Input In [18], in <cell line: 4>()`
      `1 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model`
      `2 from loss import bce_dice_loss, dice_coef`
      `----> 4 model = load_model('D:\RESEARCH\IITR\BUILDING_EXTRACTION_PhD_Final_WORK\DATASET\ISPRS_DATASET\Toronto\Toronto\ImagesDolon\output\weights\my_model.h5',`
      `5                    custom_objects={ 'bce_dice_loss': bce_dice_loss} # Load BCE Dice Loss from loss.py into model`
      `6                   )
`
`File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)`
     `65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except`
     `66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)`
`---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None`
     `68 finally:`
     `69   del filtered_tb`

`File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py:709, in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)`
    `707   obj = module_objects.get(object_name)`
    `708   if obj is None:`
`--> 709     raise ValueError(`
    `710         f'Unknown {printable_module_name}: {object_name}. Please ensure '`
    `711         'this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See '`
    `712         'https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize'`
    `713         '#registering_the_custom_object for details.')`
    `715 # Classes passed by name are instantiated with no args, functions are`
    `716 # returned as-is.`
    `717 if tf_inspect.isclass(obj):`

`ValueError: Unknown metric function: dice_coef. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.`
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. You can format it with four spaces indent.

Comment: I have included it. Actually, I am new to this forum so was a bit confused.

Comment: There are 2 different error shown (in your screenshot & pasted message, respectively), and none of them is `Model is not defined`; please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that model has been created using a custom metric, called `dice_coef`. When re-loading the model, you should add that metric too to your model creation, just as you have done for the custom loss:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from loss import bce_dice_loss, dice_coef


model = load_model(
    'D:\RESEARCH\IITR\BUILDING_EXTRACTION_PhD_Final_WORK\DATASET\ISPRS_DATASET\Toronto\Toronto\ImagesDolon\output\weights\my_model.h5',
    custom_objects={'bce_dice_loss': bce_dice_loss, 'dice_coef': dice_coef}
)
```